# Bugs eating all the leaves in the garden bed

Tags: vegetables, bugs

I see a few types of bugs in the garden bed, I'm not sure who is eating all the leaves is the veggie plants. Please help

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what type of caterpillar that is, millipedes (if that's what the second animal is) don't usually eat live plants, sowbugs (also known as wood lice) generally eat decaying material, not live plants, and the eggplant leaf is showing slug damage. Seems that you definitely have slug issues, but nothing else (unless you have actually found the caterpillar eating your vegetables). Great photos of the sowbug and slug, by the way.

Comment: will a healthy population of ants kill all the pests off?

Comment: @Black thumb - I don't think so; I really wouldn't classify millipedes and sow bugs as pests, because they're primarily scavengers and/or eat decaying wood. The best natural control for slugs is, if I remember correctly, toads. They're one of the few animals that will eat them.